# .NET 4.0 on POS Ready 2009

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, .net-framework, .net-4.0

When trying to install .NET 4.0.3 onto POS Ready 2009, I get the following error in the installation wizard:

> KB2600211 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your
>   computer.

I am using the following update:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=29053

.NET 3.5 is currently installed and I am logged in as Administrator.

Where can I see more information regarding this error?

Comment: What version of .NET 4.0 are you using exactly.  I suspect the reason the update is being blocked is because you have a version higher then 4.0.3

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I was using the wrong installer - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistakenly using the installer to update from .NET 4 to .NET 4.0.3 without having .NET 4 installed.

I am supposed to install this: [Microsoft .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851)